# I am trying to use a value from a select list with no success

Tags: javascript, select, vue.js

I have in the template of a vue component:

```
<td>
  <select id="papel" @change="intervChange(row)">
    <option value="Apreciador">Apreciar</option>
    <option value="Assessor">Assessorar</option>
    <option value="Comunicador">Comunicar</option>
    <option value="Decisor">Decidir</option>
    <option value="Executor">Executar</option>
    <option value="Iniciador">Iniciar</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

And when I try to inspect the selectdIndex the returned value is always 0.

```
methods: {
  intervChange: function(data){
    var i = document.getElementById("papel");  
    console.log(i.selectedIndex);  
    var typeInterv = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(typeInterv)
},
```

What is wrong in this approach?

Comment: So, you select something and `intervChange(row)` is called, but only 0 is returned from `console.log(i.selectedIndex); `? Btw, why do you have a `data` parameter, if you don't use it?

Comment: why not use v-model it is easy to manipulate data using v-model

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with your function calling
You have used  @change="intervChange(row)"
Now this row parameter is whats creating problem.
Just remove data parameter from function and row from function call and its gonna work.

```
function intervChange() {

     var i = document.getElementById("papel");
     console.log(i.selectedIndex);
     var typeInterv = i.options[i.selectedIndex].value;
     console.log(typeInterv)
 }
<select id="papel" onchange="intervChange();">
    <option value="Apreciador">Apreciar</option>
    <option value="Assessor">Assessorar</option>
    <option value="Comunicador">Comunicar</option>
    <option value="Decisor">Decidir</option>
    <option value="Executor">Executar</option>
    <option value="Iniciador">Iniciar</option>
  </select>
```

I tested this and it worked

Comment: Yes, but I want to change row inside the function in order to pass the new value to the parent component...

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a vue subcomponent, now a generic subcomponent:

```js
Vue.component('select-value-from-list', {
  template: `
    <select v-model="current-value">
        <option v-for='op in options' :value='op.value'>{{op.label}}</option>
    </select>
  `,
  props: {
      options: {
          type: Array,
          required: true
      }
  },
  data: function() {
      return {
          "current-value": "Apreciador"
      }
  },
  watch: {
        current-value: function () {
            this.$emit('value-change', this.current-value);
        }
  }
})
```

That I use in the simplest way:

```html
<td>
  <select-value-from-list 
    :options = "[{label: 'Apreciar', value: 'Apreciador'},
                {label: 'Assessorar', value: 'Assessor'},
                {label: 'Comunicar', value: 'Comunicador'},
                {label: 'Decidir', value: 'Decisor'},
                {label: 'Executar', value: 'Executor'},
                {label: 'Iniciar', value: 'Iniciador'}]"
    @value-change="mudarIntervencao($event, row)"
  />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want in this way

```
<td>
<select id='app' @change=intervChange() >
    <option v-for='op in options' :value='op.value'>{{op.text}}</option>
</select>
</td>

<script>
    var vm= new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            options: [
                {value:"Apreciador", text:'Apreciar'},
                {value:"Assessor", text:'Assessorar'},
                {value:"Comunicador", text:'Comunicar'},
                {value:"Decisor", text:'Decidir'}
            ]
        },
        methods:{
            intervChange: function() {
                opindex=this.$el.selectedIndex
                opvalue=this.options[opindex].value;
                console.log(opindex +':'+opvalue);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```